# How to import phpDoc into Confluence?

Tags: phpdoc, confluence

I'm looking for proper way to use phpDoc-comments from project to generate developer's documentation inside my Confluence 4.1.4.

Answer (score 6):

One approach I've been looking at is to deploy my HTML output (similar to phpDoc) as a second web app on Confluence's instance of Tomcat, and then to iFrame that doc into a Confluence page. It doesn't integrate with Confluence's searching/indexing or labelling, but it should play nicely with the Crowd authentication scheme that we've set up. I figure I could then use a federated search tool to search across the two web apps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for the same solution. The closest I have come is using html2wiki which has a dialect for Confluence. I created a PHP script that recurses through my api directory and processes each html page with this html2wiki program. Unfortunately, it does not perfectly format the markup and leaves undesired html artifacts.

My next approach is to try and tweak the dialect myself to try and resolve the poor formatting.

http://search.cpan.org/~diberri/HTML-WikiConverter-0.51/bin/html2wiki

Comment: Lately, i've been looking into writing my own converter which extends the phpDocumentor converter class so that I can directly manipulate the data into a Confluence markup. Having some difficulty doing this though since the only examples I can base off of are those that come with phpdoc i.e. HTML, PDF, XML, and CHM. The problem is that all of these generate an index of all the classes, etc, when all I need is to create a single Confluence wiki page for each class file. Please let me know if you have made any more leeway on this. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Docs Plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.meixxi.confluence.docs.docs-plugin. This plugin enables you to upload and publish your PHPDocs and other HTML and JavaScript based content in Confluence.

Docs provides also a REST Interface in order to automate the publishing process. So, publishing of the PHPDocs can become part of the Continuous Integartion Process. A technical documentation as well as a sample code can you find here: https://bitbucket.org/meixxi/docs-plugin/wiki/Home